# React: Missing return type on function. eslint(@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I'm new to Typescript React. In a really basic functional component, eslint is complaining me it's missing the returned type for the functional component itself. Where I'm wrong?

[image]

Comment: just disable this rule in lint config. "explicit type retur". and i would recommended you yo use tslint insteed of eslint since you are using typescript

Comment: Thanks @JurajKocan, it seems to be that Typescript is moving to eslint. Search for "eslint" in this article: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29288#developer-productivity-tools-and-integration
That's why I chose eslint over tslint.

Comment: ...and I don't want to disable the rule, but understand how to avoid breaking it and made my code better and cleaner! ;-)

Comment: hm interesting, i didnt know about that... if you dont want to disable this rule you will be force to write return type to all your function. so just write return type. In your image there is only type for constant, but not return type of the function. And not all eslint rules are good for you. people can have other opinions. i would disable this rule. Infer type are ts feature that make easier your life. you have still strict type.

Comment: type Props = { title: string };

const Test: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ title }): React.ReactElement<Props> => (<div>{title}</div>);

Comment: In TypeScript this link is very helpful: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As explained by Nicholas Tower in this answer [Typescript | Warning about Missing Return Type of function, ESLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814753/typescript-warning-about-missing-return-type-of-function-eslint?answertab=active#tab-top), depending on the react version that you are using, you can use any of the lines below:

If you're on the latest react version (16.8.0 or later), do this:
`const Component: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props: Props) => { }`

Prior to 16.8, you'd instead do:
`const Component: React.SFC<Props> = (props: Props) => {}`

Where SFC stands for "stateless functional component".

EDIT:------

Based on @SergioP's comment, a more idiomatic solution would be

`const Test = ({ title }: Props): JSX.Element => <div>{title}</div>`

Comment: I'm on React 16.8.5, it's a fresh new project. The syntax I used is supposed to be correct, why eslint is complaining? Could it be a wrong eslint configuration?

Comment: With this syntax the linter doesn't complain: `const Test = ({ title }: Props): JSX.Element => <div>{title}</div>`

Answer (score 7):

I too faced this issue.

```
const handleLogout = () => {
router.push('/')
}
```

The above code given same issue to me, then code is updated like below, then error disappear in my case

```
const handleLogout = (): void => {
router.push('/')
}
```

Reference Link:
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-function-return-type.md