# Escaping ESLint Missing return type on function in React typescript function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I have a javascript function e.g.:

```
export default () => ({
  root: css`
    background-color: hotpink;
    margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
  `,
});
```

But here ESLint is complaining?

```
Missing return type on function.eslint@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
```

Or a functional React component:

```
const Header: FC<Props> = ({ siteTitle }) => {

  return (
    <header>
        <h1>
           {siteTitle}
        </h1>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

I like to write my functional component like:

```
const Header = ({ siteTitle }: Props) => {

  return (
    <header>
        <h1>
           {siteTitle}
        </h1>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

But then I get also: `Missing return type on function.eslint@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types`

What do I have to do?

Comment: Type the return value of the function. (Or disable the rule, as I'd prefer - letting TS infer things implicitly is just fine the vast majority of the time IMO)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: Missing return type on function. eslint(@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56519019/react-missing-return-type-on-function-eslinttypescript-eslint-explicit-funct)

Answer (score 0):

@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",

Comment: Hello. Code-only answer should be avoided. Please consider adding some explanation.