# Why does my code type get a warning?　"warning Missing return type on function"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am making an icon component using svg.
My code type gives a warning.

"warning  Missing return type on function"
I want to use svg as a component.
eslint warning is displayed.

```
import * as React from "react";

export const Icon = () => {
  return (
    <svg viewBox="">
      <path
       ・
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　・
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　・
      />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript | Warning about Missing Return Type of function, ESLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814753/typescript-warning-about-missing-return-type-of-function-eslint)

Answer (score 0):

To supress eslint warning you can use /* eslint-disable */ at the top.

Answer (score 0):

- [What is the TypeScript return type of a React stateless component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133420/what-is-the-typescript-return-type-of-a-react-stateless-component)
- [Typescript | Warning about Missing Return Type of function, ESLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814753/typescript-warning-about-missing-return-type-of-function-eslint)

There is more information about it.

You need to set the type of the function.

Also, as phoenix567sid said. You can add `/* eslint-disable */` but I not recommend to do this. The eslint is not meant to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you. My problem has been solved.**

```
import * as React from "react";

export const Icon = ():JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <svg viewBox="">
      <path
       ・
　　　     　・
　　　　     ・
      />
    </svg>
  );
};
```